# Django undefined symbol: PyUnicode_AsUTF8

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python/Django. I have set up the environment needed to run Django project.When I'm trying to migrate an existing project , it shows up this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module:   
/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.6-py3.2-linux-i686.egg
/_mysql.cpython-32mu.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_AsUTF8
```

Please can anyone figure out the reason for this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in `mysqlclient`. There are some compatibility issues in `mysqlclient` with Python's 3.2 version. Apparently, `mysqlclient` is still not supported in Python 3.2.

Check this `django-developers` google group thread where this issue was raised and discussed.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/n-TI8mBcegE

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the `mysql` code needs to access symbols that your Python interpreter isn't making available. Perhaps you could load the `python-dev` package, which contains them (though I don't ever remember having to do that myself).