# Just Can't Get MySQL working with Python/Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've read so many articles, I'm blind, but I'm sure to one of you this will be simple...

I have setup a VPS on MyHosting running Ubuntu 12.04.  Try as I might, I can't get MySQL running with Django. When I run python3 manage.py migrate I get an error ending with:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I got to this point by:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo pip3 install django
```

The above installed Python 3.2.3
django version:  1.8.4
mysql version: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44

I edited settings.py to include the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

PS Apache version: Apache/2.2.22

Comment: PS I also tried configuring the database ENGINE option to django.db.backends.mysql

Comment: You need to install the MySQL-Python package: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29150749/240418

Comment: Forgot to say that I tried that.  Just tried again:

    pip3 install MySQL-python

    ImportError: No module named ConfigParser

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't support Python 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14087705/240418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Django docs recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) you use mysqlclient, a Python 3 compatible fork of MySQLDB.

You should be able to install it with:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

It might be better to use a virtualenv, in which case you can use `pip` instead of `pip3` in the virtualenv.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Your databases backend should be `django.db.backends.mysql`.

However, mysqlclient requires Python 3.3+ for Python 3. If you want to run Django with MySQL, I believe your options are currently either Python 2.7 or 3.3+.

Comment: I ran

    pip3 install mysqlclient

successfully, and it installed version 1.3.6

But when I then tried 

    python3 manage.py migrate

I got this error:

ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/_mysql.cpython-32mu.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_AsUTF8

Comment: Ah, it looks like mysqlclient [isn't compatible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414327/django-undefined-symbol-pyunicode-asutf8) with Python 3.2. Is it possible to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4? Otherwise, using 12.04 with Python 2.7 might be easiest.

Comment: I'll try uninstalling Python3 (and I guess Django, too)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    pip install MySQL-python
```

If you receive error **mysql_config not found**

Run

```
    sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```