# Unable to connect to MySql with Django & Python3.4

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to build out a web application using Django and Python3.4 through Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition on a Windows 10 machine. I want to use MySQL as the database, but I'm unable to connect to the DB using python3.4 -- it comes up with:

`No Module named MySQlDB error`

Can someone please tell me how I can fix this. I do not want to downgrade my python version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb

Comment: With Python 3.4, try using mysqlclient. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401793/just-cant-get-mysql-working-with-python-django/32402672#32402672

Comment: It just downloaded a mysqlclient folder.. how do I go about installing this ? Sorry, I'm new to this..

Comment: The easiest way to install is using pip: `pip install mysqlclient`. It will download the package and install.

Comment: That actually worked !! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Ok.. I seem to have encountered a new problem... So I was able to connect to the Database through an existing project, but again got the 'No Module called MySqlDb' error when I created a new project and tried to connect from it.. What exactly is going on ?